# Check if string is in format dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: objective-c, string, date, format

I wanna check if a string is in format dd.mm.yyyy, like

```
if(myString is in format dd.mm.yyyy) {
  NSLog(@"Ok");
}
else{
  NSLog(@"No");
```

Comment: Use `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a code like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01.01.1970"; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";
if ([dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]) {
    //YES
}
```

Why `NSDateFormatter`: it was created to parse dates. Plus, this way you get an easy way to change date format and as a side effect, get a valid `NSDate` object that you can work with.

However, if you are intending to use this `dateFormatter` often (for instance, it is used inside a `UITableViewCell`), you might encounter performance issues. If you did, and you're sure that `NSDateFormatter` is what is causing it (Instruments might help you here), you could reuse your `dateFormatter`. For example, like so:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01.01.1970"; 
static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";
});

if ([dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString]) {
    //YES
}
```

It seems (it is my guess based on tests that I ran) that the first call to `dateFromString` triggers lazy initialization inside the `dateFormatter`, and it takes some time (several tests results are below). If you reuse it, the `NSDateFormatter` initialization is performed only once.

On my iPhone 5S with iOS 8.4.1 the `dispatch_once` version works about 10 times faster:

> `dispatch_once`: 0.536 seconds, recreation: 5.475 seconds
>   (time to parse 10.000 dates)

In the same test @zaph got a 2x performance difference on his iPhone 6S with iOS 9.x:

> `dispatch_once`: 0.57 seconds, recreation: 1.01 seconds
>   (time to parse 10.000 dates)

So, it depends on the device, the OS version and on how intensively you're going to use that dateFormatter. In some cases the second code fragment might be an overkill. But I encountered situations where it provided a noticeable performance boost.

**UPD:** Also note that quite often American dates are also written with a dot as a separator, so what seems to be a `dd.MM.yyyy` date might actually be a `MM.dd.yyyy` date (e.g. April 5th instead of May 4th). For dates with `dd > 12` it's not an issue, but otherwise it is. I don't think there's anything you could do about that without an additional context though, so just be warned.

Comment: I can't imagine why someone would down vote this answer.

Comment: How expensive is creating an `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: @zaph, it's significantly expensive. It's not something you'd like to do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. for instance (I know because it encountered disappointing performance because of it). I will update my answer in a minute with a small demo and a test result.

Comment: What is "significantly expensive" expensive in seconds?

Comment: Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" and Kent Beck: "Do the Simplest Thing that Could Possibly Work". Zaph: "Don't optimize without measuring first." It is complexity that leads to failing code.

Comment: @zaph I wouldn't write `dispatch_once` just to "act cool". It's based on experience. When I encountered a performance decrease (twitchy scrolling) in my UITableView, I profiled my program (because, as you noted, premature optimization is a bad practice) and found out that the reason was the `NSDateFormatter` recreation. I've added a small demo to make the answer more well-reasoned.

Comment: Having found that `NSDateFormatter` was in the past an optimization candidate does not carry forward. I too have seen this. But the use case needs to be examined and in general a measurement needs to be made to determine if there is a problem and if so exactly where.

Comment: @zaph, well, yes, I do. Because that's how you use a dateFormatter: You create it, you set a date format (did you set a date format when you tried it on iPhone 6S?) and you parse a date/format a date. And you either create it once or you recreate it every time. But in any case you use it. And that's what I do. And the result above shows, that creating it once + using it is 10 times faster, than recreating it every time + using it.

Comment: The `dispatch_once` needs to be inside the timing test.

Comment: @zaph, oh, I understand now. I tried again with `dispatch_once` inside the block. The result is almost the same: 0.241 vs. 0.026. However, I thought: if the creation is cheap, but recreation is efficient, then probably `NSDateFormatter` is lazily initialized during the first call to the `dateFromString`. And it seems to be the case. Here is another test I did: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HbKFxiDi).

Comment: The `dispatch_once` needs to be inside the timing test. With `dispatch_once_t` the time per iteration is 29us, without the time is 102us so the cost of instantiating `NSDateFormatter` is 73us which ios the answer to  my original question. Tested on an iPhone 6s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91029/discussion-between-freenickname-and-zaph).

Answer (score 2):

You can using Regex to check it.
For example this code using Regex to check "mm.dd.yyyy":

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *expForreg = @"^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\\.](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))[\\.](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|((2|02)[\\.](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9]))))[\\.]\\d{4}$|^\\d{4}$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:expForreg
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:@"10.30.1989" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"10.30.1989" length])];
if(matches && matches.count > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Ok");
}else
{
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Why not use an `NSDateFormatter`? That regex is crazy. Does it handle leap years?

Comment: @rmaddy: in this case (only "mm.dd.yyyy"), i think NSDateFormatter is correct option. But, if you want to allow check "mm/dd/mmmm", "mm-dd-yyyy",... Try using Regex.

Comment: Huh? `NSDateFormatter` is the proper choice regardless of the date format. That's its purpose.

Comment: @Franken, but the OP wants "dd.mm.yyyy", not "mm.dd.yyyy" :) And there is a problem: rewriting this regexp into a regexp for "dd.mm.yyyy" (MM actually, not mm, but never mind) is... tricky :) Especially half a year after you wrote it. Still, I agree, that a regexp can be used to check if date is valid in several formats. But it would make this regexp even bigger and scarier, so I wouldn't use it if it was for me :) Besides, your regexp thinks that `02.29.2015` is a valid date. Which is false, since it is not a leap year. Regexps are tricky :)

Comment: @Franken, And `0001` is, on the other hand, a "correct" date. Here is you regexp in a visual debugger: [debuggex link](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YI1GSAqRFk8oPQb_)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
NSString *testString = @"11.22.3333";

NSString *pattern = @"^\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}$";
NSRange range = [testString rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Ok");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Bit that is not really a good date test.